# Associate text from source code line to line - too fragile

Tags: c++, c, text

I need to associate textual data with the lines in a source code file. Something like "these lines are to create a Myclass object" -> lines from 20 to 32.

The problem is that this kind of line tracking is highly fragile: it is sufficient that someone adds a newline to break my correspondence between associated text and lines.

I need an idea to make this link a bit stronger (not too much but at least resisting to a few line shifts), suggestions are greatly welcome.

Comment: C/C++ source code files, but yes the app is under windows

Comment: Where are the associations being presented? Could you use comments in the code to wrap the sections, and then generate the associations by running the source files through a script? The comment wrappers would generally move with the associated code.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar - why?  Let me guess, 'Microsoft Code! The latest addition to the Office suite for 2013!   Quickly and easily comment/annotate your code!  Merely navigate a shapeless array of incomprehesible and unintuitive toolbars and ribbon controls to write your 'Hello World' program in under a day, with full commenting in 1045 different fonts!  Introductory offer, only $599!'.

Comment: @farski, I don't like this solution very much because it's pretty messed up.. I don't like messing with source code files either

Comment: @MartinJames Not really.. [DIA SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx) lets your query PDB's and you can find this information from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution would be to hash (`md5` is pretty easy and accessible) the lines and store the hash along the data.

You can then check the hash against the possibly modified file. If it matches, great, otherwise begin checking previous/next lines for a match.

Comment: @AdamLiss I was just treating the problem in the question, mainly " it is sufficient that someone adds a newline to break my correspondence between associated text and lines.". If a line is edited, that would suck :)

Comment: I agree that this would be good and easy to implement.. there's the problem that if a user selects a "var = 22;" line, that might be present n-additional times in the source code thus messing my hash correspondence

Comment: @JohnnyPauling deriving logical context from surrounding code, seems to me, is a much bigger and complicated issue.

Comment: uhm I was also thinking about storing the number of lines each block is made of, along the hash of the entire block. And then use some kind of a "sliding window" for the entire source code .. something like starting with the first N lines at the beginning and calculating the hash to see if these are the lines I need. This would be great but AWFULLY slow

Answer (score 2):

One approach might be to enlist the help of a source control system. For example, using Git, you could associate textual data with a specific *version* of the source code. If the source code is changed, you can use a "diff" algorithm to discover which line(s) have been added or removed. Using that delta information, you can then update your annotation lines (for example, adding a line at the top of the file would cause your 20-32 annotation to move to 21-33).

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to implement some form of automatic documentation system? If so, then basing this around line numbering is indeed fragile. I would suggest using some sort of markup to associate the text with semantic blocks of code that are robust when moved or altered. Perhaps something along the lines of `doxygen` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't really like the idea of having the source code messed up with additional comments which may worsen readability, otherwise this would be a great solution

Comment: If written in a disciplined fashion, doxygen comments serve double duty as templates for exporting documentation and implementing the inline documentation itself. Comments should never obfuscate, but in general the rule should be that if someone else encountered a block of your code and a comment would be helpful in aiding understanding, then comment it. In six months' or a year's time, you will be that someone else.